# Array.map not reconginizing the array and not printing data

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I have a simple function component, where I am making a `.get() call` and then later in my `jsx` I am just `mapping through using .map()` an array to print data.

But for some reason, the `array` is not recognizable and it is not printing the data.

`useEffect()` is working fine. It is logging out data. But, the `books array` is just not working and I'm unable to figure out why

below is the code.

```
 const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get("database.json")
      .then((response) => {
        const request = response.data.results.books;
        console.log("request", request);
        setBooks(books);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Data is loading...</p>;
  }

  if (error || !Array.isArray(books)) {
    return <p>There was an error loading your data!</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <h2>LOREN IPSUM</h2>
      <div className="row__posters">
        {books.map((book) => (
          <img
            // onClick={() => handleClick(book)}
            key={book.title}
            className="row__poster row__posterLarge"
            src={book.book_image}
            alt={book.title}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      {/* {description && <span /> />} */}
    </div>
```

);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setBooks(books);`

You are updating the books with their current value.

=> Change this to `setBooks(request);`

Comment: And unrelated to this answer: `request` is a confusing variable name for your request's results.